# Find all rows with same value in a column to determine min/max values in other columns of those rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, in columns A:D, with input and output times.

I would like to put the cycle time in a graphic.
[image]

In the red box are serial numbers. In the yellow box are the start times and in the green box the end times. There are not always 3 same serial numbers (e.g. 6 same serial numbers).
To display the cycle time I need the earliest start time from the yellow box (min) and the maximum from the green box as end time (max) from one serial number.

This is not possible manually, because the sheet is too large. The problem is not to find the min out of the yellow box and the max out of the green box, but to search the column for same serial numbers.

Comment: It is good to know that in case of placing such pictures, you should show the columns headers, too. So, are the columns of the range you show A:D? If not, what columns do you show? Then, are the values (except the first column) formatted as `Date`? Or as text?

Comment: yes indeed, A:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next solution/code. Since you did not answer the clarification questions, it assumes that the shown columns are "A:D" and time in columns "B:D" is formatted as `Date` (`"hh:mm:ss"`). The code uses a dictionary to keep unique  serial numbers and calculate/store te minimum of second column and maximum of the fourth one. The serial numbers may appear **in any order**:

```
Sub ExtractMinMaxDates()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, arr, arrEl, arrFin
   Dim key As Variant, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)    'iterate between the array rows
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'if a dictionary key has not been created:
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 4)) 'make it and place (as item) an array containing
        Else                                                'time from columns 2 and 4
            arrEl = dict(arr(i, 1))                         'place the item in an array
            If arr(i, 2) < arrEl(0) Then arrEl(0) = arr(i, 2) 'keep the minimum
            If arr(i, 4) > arrEl(1) Then arrEl(1) = arr(i, 4) 'keep the maximum
        End If
   Next i
   'Redim the final array to keep the dictionary data:
   ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 3): i = 1

   'fill the final aray with the necesssary data
   For Each key In dict.Keys
        arrFin(i, 1) = key: arrFin(i, 2) = dict(key)(0)
        arrFin(i, 3) = dict(key)(1): i = i + 1
   Next
   
   'Drop the array content at once anf format the necessary columns:
   With sh.Range("F2").Resize(dict.count, 3) 'it may return anywhere (just change "F2" with needed cell)
        .Value2 = arrFin
        .Columns(2).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        .Columns(3).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
  End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly fine in my use case, thank you! Great help.